# thermal (hot springs) destinations in Europe for young couples

Tags: europe, lakes, hot-springs

When we search the web for *Europe Hot Springs* and similar terms we get a lot of results.

We have found that many thermal baths are often visited by older people for medical reasons.

We are looking for popular (large facilities) where young couples and / or couples with small children can be found. Where patients, people who visit the thermal baths for health reasons are less represented.

It would be ideal if you could do something in the area in the evening (go out).

I am looking for popular natural hot water in Europe targeting young couples and families with small kids.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Are you looking for hot springs with natural hot water or simply a spa? Berlin/Germany has this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_Islands_Resort

Comment: Check out Therme Erding

Comment: I think the target audience should be fairly obvious from any establishment's web pages. Be aware, that at least in Germany, children are often not allowed everywhere. Larger baths often have one section with swimming-pools, play-grounds and 'have-fun' areas and a separate spa and sauna section not open to children.

Comment: see edit, last line

Comment: Iceland has everything hot spring related.

Answer (score 1):

### Austria, Germany, Switzerland

Search terms:

- Erlebnisbad, Spaßbad, Wasserpark (any kind of water, with water slides, etc.)
- Therme, Thermalbad (thermal baths, often focused on health)

Some baths combine both categories, e.g. [Therme Erding](https://www.therme-erding.de/en/) has 27 water slides as well as a separate area dedicated to health and wellness.

Some lists (in German, featuring mostly the same destinations):

- [Erlebnisbäder in Deutschland](https://www.deutschlands-schoenste-reiseziele.de/reiseziele-in-deutschland-finden/erlebnisbaeder-in-deutschland/)
- [Die 20 besten Spaß- und Erlebnisbäder Deutschlands](https://www.travelbook.de/ziele/spassbaeder/die-spassigsten-erlebnisbaeder-deutschlands)
- [Die 11 besten Wasserparks und Erlebnisbäder in Deutschland](https://www.voucherwonderland.com/reisemagazin/erlebnisbaeder-deutschland/)

For translations, try [DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/translator).

Comment: The first category you are describing is not what OP is asking about (baths around hot springs), but regular swimming pools/parks.